# Set backround color of listview item

Tags: java, android

So the lisview Item background should change its color if the item contains String s "CLOSED";

I am working with Async tasks:

Code:

```java
private class GetTodo extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {         
        //myCode
    }           

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        setTodoid(todoid);
        setState(state);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        for (int i = 0; i < arrlist.size(); i++) {
            if (arrlist.get(i).getDone() == "CLOSED"){
                listView.setBackgroundColor(getColor(R.color.design_default_color_error));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And if the Arraylist item on index is "CLOSED" the background color of the listitem should be red.

Answer (score 0):

you have to change your item color in your Adapter in `onBindViewHolder` method.

like

```
if (item.getDone() == "CLOSED"){
        yourItemViewParentId.setBackgroundColor(getColor(R.color.design_default_color_error));
    }else{
        yourItemViewParentId.setBackgroundColor(getColor(R.color.your_default_color));
    }
```

What do you mean with yourItemViewID.

I have a xml file for the item which called list_item.xml

I'm asking here because I can't add a comment.

**Update :**

yourItemViewId means id of your parent layout of list_item.xml

Comment: You should compare `Strings` with `equals()` instead of `==`

Comment: share your list_item.xml file .